# Checking patent application's status before it is published

Tags: status

I filed a patent application through a US attorney. He gave me a receipt "Electronic Acknowledgement Receipt" bearing EFS ID, Application Number, Confirmation Number etc.  But I also want to see the status of the filing.

is there a way I can do it myself ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to your question, but is there a reason your attorney can't check for you? He or she could surely just pop onto Private PAIR and look it up without whatever bureaucratic hoops you'd undoubtedly find yourself jumping through to get access yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the MPEP section 203.08

Inquiries as to the status of applications, by persons entitled to the information, should be answered promptly. Simple letters of inquiry regarding the status of applications will be transmitted from the Office of Patent Application Processing to the TCs for direct action. Such letters will be stamped “Status Letters.”

If the correspondent is not entitled to the information, in view of 37 CFR 1.14, he or she should be so informed.

Comment: Who is the person entitled to the information? Inventor or the Attorney ?